Django - Uploaded images are not found in production
I have a problem uploading images in production in my Django project.
I'm converting canvas to png and then I upload them in a hidden input, then I save them in the database in the views.
In development it works as expected, but in production, I get 404 images not found.
Folder Structure
website/
|
|- core/
|    |- settings.py
|    |- urls.py
|    ...
|
|- management/
|    |- models.py
|    ...
|
|- static/
|   |- images/
|      |- uploads/
|         |- sketch/
|          ...
|    ...
|
|- manage.py
|- media/
|   |- uploads/
|      |- sketch/
|        ...

settings.py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static',
]

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles'

models.py
class OrderSketch(models.Model):
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/sketch/')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Sketch - {self.order.id}'

index.html
<div class="sketch-gallery">
    {% for sketch in order.ordersketch_set.all %}
        <img class="gallery-image {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %}" src="{{ sketch.img.url }}" alt="Order Sketch {{ forloop.counter }}">
    {% endfor %}
</div>

urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('base.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

views.py
if request.POST.getlist('sketch_images[]'):
    for image_data in request.POST.getlist('sketch_images[]'):
        format, imgstr = image_data.split(';base64,')
        ext = format.split('/')[1]  # Extract file extension from format (e.g., 'png' from 'image/png')
        img_file = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(imgstr), name=f'temp.{ext}')
        
        # Save the image to the database
        order_sketch = OrderSketch(order=order, img=img_file)
        order_sketch.save()

Note: my website is hosted in Microsoft Azure

Do you serve MEDIA files by Nginx or some other webserver?

Django does not serve static/media files in production mode.

No I'm not using Nginx... And sorry I'm new to Django

Is settings.DEBUG True?

No it's not, DEBUG = False. Actually problem is solved thank you anyway, I had to create a resource in Microsoft Azure called "Storage Accounts" that contains all the data (files objects)
